# Adding IF clause to zend framework 1 database table select object

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is my sql:

```
    SELECT id,`status`,IF(`status` = 'active', 'deleted','active') AS `status-use`
    FROM categories
```

And here is my code: (`ActionResourceModel` is a `Zend_Db_Table` )

```
            $dbTable = $this->getActionResourceModel();
            $select = $dbTable->select();
            $select->from($dbTable,$this->getQueryColumns());
            $select->order($orderClause.' '.$orderSpec);
```

How do I add to my select object :

```
IF(`status` = 'active', 'deleted','active') AS `status-use`
```

Comment: Now we have your SQL, we have your code, only a question is missing!

Comment: @Rizier123 haha. i was just fixing that.

Comment: @jkushner: Still, what is actually your question? Downvoting.

Comment: Why down voting??? The question is clear. i think you should read more about Zend_Db_Table! @usr1234567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select should look like:

```
$dbTable = $this->getActionResourceModel();
$select = $dbTable->select();
$select->from(
        $dbTable, 
        array(
            'status-use' => new Zend_Db_Expr("IF(`status` = 'active', 'deleted','active')"
        )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend from `Zend_Db_Table` and define a function that create this query.  you could see `Zend_Db_Table` functions like `join`, `from`, etc for design your special class